# how to find x number of documents where one property matches but other are distinct

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Ok, imagine a collection like this:

```
[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5f76eb2bfe4a1e9c473bd2"),
    "machine" : "NY-D800",
    "level" : "Fatal",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5f76eb2bfe4a1e9c473bd2"),
    "machine" : "NY-D889",
    "level" : "Fatal",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5f76eb2bfe4a1e9c473bd2"),
    "machine" : "NY-D889",
    "level" : "Info",
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5f76eb2bfe4a1e9c473bd2"),
    "machine" : "NY-D800",
    "level" : "Fatal",
},
...
]
```

I want to find documents that have `level` set to 'Fatal' but I don't want to return duplicates (duplicate `machine`). So for example 'NY-D800' is listed twice with 'Fatal' so I would want it to be returned only once. Finally I would like to limit the values returned to 10 items.

Recapping:

1. `level` = 'Fatal'
2. only unique values determined by `machine`
3. limit to 10 docs

Is this possible with MongoDB, Mongoose?

I tried this:

```
 Logs
    .distinct({'level': 'Fatal'})
    .limit(10)
    .exec(function (err, response){
        var result = {
            status: 201,
            message: response
        };
        if (err){
            result.status = 500;
            result.message = err;
        } else if (!response){
            result.status = 404;
            result.message = err;
        }
        res.status(result.status).json(result.message);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) with the `level` "Fatal" and then apply [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with `machine`

```
Logs.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "level": "Fatal" }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$machine",
    "level": { "$first": "$level" },
  }},
  { "$limit": 10 },
  { "$project": { "machine": "$_id", "level": 1, "_id": 0 }}
])
```

Comment: Your solution works great! Thanks. One more follow up. If my documents had more properties than just machine and level...is there a way to include other properties?

Comment: You can use `$first` just as I have used for `level`